# C++ inheritance and casting problems

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

So I have this class and struct:

```cpp
class ISDFParams
{
public:
    virtual ~ISDFParams() = default;
    Vector3 point;
};

struct SDFSphereParams : public ISDFParams {
public:
    float radius;
};
```

I use it later like this

```cpp
SDFSphereParams p;
p.radius = 4;

GetDensityData(p);
```

In `GetDensityData(ISDFParams sdfParams)` I do

```cpp
SDFSphereParams* _params = (SDFSphereParams*)&params;
```

The problem is when I print `_params->radius` its anything else but **4**.

What am I doing wrong?

*P.S. I know the example is a bit pointless, but the original code is rather long so I cut down it my problem.*

Comment: you are trying to copy construct base class object using derived class variable. `GetDensityData(ISDFParams sdfParams)` method actually copies `ISDFParams` part of  your object hence it does not contain derived class variable `radius` hence it prints garbage value.

Comment: That can't be right? `_params` is a pointer. So you have to use `_params->radius`. You also don't actually show how you are displaying the value.

Comment: Change `GetDensityData` to take the object by reference

Comment: @AndrewTruckle yes I do with ->, wrote by mistake

Comment: @AlanBirtles can you write answer. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: He can’t write an answer as your question was closed.

Comment: Search passing by reference. It is very easy.